# ProgressDialog not showing

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have declared a simple `ProgressDialog` in my android application but it isn't showing up. Here is my instantiation:

```
ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this, ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
pDialog.setMessage("Logging in...");
pDialog.show();
```

I am pretty new to Android development but not Java; does anybody see anything that I might be doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
It's weird, in the block that is supposed to dismiss the dialog, I have a content view switch, and if I comment out the dismissal the dialog will actually show AFTER the content switch. Here is said block:

```
if(writeSuccess){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    pDialog.dismiss();
    setContentView(R.layout.auth);
}
```

Comment: Can you show use some more code (like - where is this code located...)?

Comment: It is located in a `public` authorization method directly under the main Activity Class

Comment: Geographic location won't help too much :) Is it running on main thread? is it running in a loop ?

Comment: it is *not* running in a loop and is in the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this.

```
ProgressDialog pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "MY Dialog", "Please wait...");
```

By this single line also you will have a ProgressDialog.

Answer (score 1):

If this code is not located inside the `MyActivity` class, then `MyActivity.this` cannot be resolved.

You also need a proper [**`context`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) for creating [progress dialogs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html), that is, if you are trying to create a dialog before [`onCreate`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html) has been called on your activity, then your context reference (`MyActivity.this`) will be invalid.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing MyActivity.this with getApplicationContext(). If that doesn't work, do you get anything in your logcat when the dialog should be opening?

Comment: It actually throws an fatal exception when refering to my app through the `getApplicationContext()` method. It is an `IllegalStateException` thrown when attempting to show the `ProgressDialog`

Comment: To create a Dialog, you need an Activity Context or a Service Context, not an Application Context.